# "expr" in SQL Server Reporting Services 2008

Tags: sql, reporting-services

> In SQL Server Business Intelligence
>   Development Studio 2008(BIDS), the
>   designer will replace a complex
>   expression with < EXPR >
>   automatically.

Any idea why that is?  Can I switch it back to how it was in Reporting Services 2005, where it showed the actual expression instead of a useless "EXPR"???

Comment: After looking at the answers below, I am very sad that this is an example of backwards progress for SSRS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a Label value, which is used to display a useful value in the design surface only.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can but if you double click the `<expr>` on your report it will allow you to view/edit it, you can also right click and select an option from the context menu to edit it.